# Python: sklearn generate clusters with within a specified range for data-points

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-generation

I am trying to generate a cluster within the range of x such that 0 < x < 10 and the within range of y such that 0 < y < 10 with the center x = 5 and y = 5. I can't find any solutions on-line. Can anyone help me with this. Below is what I got so far

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from pylab import *

    centers = [[5, 5]]
    X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.5, random_state=0)
    print X

Example of Output:
 [ 5.07747371  5.18908126]
 [ 4.6781908   3.88829842]
 [ 5.03325861  5.15123595]
 [ 4.44780833  5.02608254]
 [ 4.77223375  5.00873958]
 [ 5.76638961  5.73467938]
 [ 5.08871307  4.79910953]
 [ 4.68207696  5.33821665]
 [ 5.58938979  4.91003758]
```

As you can see, the output values have x varying from 4 to 6 and the same for y. I need to be able to generate clusters where I can control this range.

Answer (score 0):

`make_blobs` generates *Gaussian* clusters. These do *not* have a finite value range. Values outside a few standard deviations are unlikely, but not impossible. If you want to guarantee the value range, use a uniform distribution instead.

You can use `centers` to control the centers, and `cluster_std` to control the standard deviations. See the documentation of `make_blobs` for details.

Alternatively, if your application allows it, you can simply throw away values outside the range you request effectively sampling from a truncated Gaussian. Finally, if it is not a valid option to throw away samples (for whatever reason), you can indeed sample two uniform numbers. And if you insist on getting a Gaussian distribution, you can Box-Muller transform the two uniform numbers into a 2D Gaussian (in the link: compute z1 and z2 from two uniform numbers between 0 and 1: x1 and x2):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Box-MullerTransformation.html